# Magento2.3.0 Categories - I wish the products which are in child category will be visible in each parent category by default

Tags: admin, magento2.3, category-products, create-product

I am using in Magento2.3.0 when i create product in admin side i need to Categories - I wish the products which are in child category will be visible in each parent category by default.

adding the products automatically to the parent category and to the subcategories which are on higher level

so if anyone idea reply me how to achieve this requirement

below sample image added which i define i needed

[image]

Answer (score 0):

disable the anchor option in all subcatogery

[image]

Comment: if disable than layer navigation inside category working

Comment: I disable on subcategory but all category display in our  product edit inside category section